# Is it possible to use two cells of criteria to return a value from a third column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an Google sheets file with two sheets. I'm trying to reference one sheet's text based on two cells of criteria using a formula in the other sheet. I have one sheet that looks similar to this -

[image: Sheet 1]

And another that looks like this -

[image: Sheet 2]

I would like to put a formula on the second sheet that basically says - look on the first sheet for the values in columns A and B and return me the value in column C. The tricky part is - the values in the second sheet may be inverted or there may be an instance where only one value is present, like in row 1 in the first sheet. Also the formula should only fill in a value if both columns match. All text combinations in both sheets are unique.

Is it possible to do this with text? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Would it help to create a virtual column which concats the two together (ideally sorted first so you don't have to deal with permutations)?

Comment: I had thought of that. Problem is the values on sheet 2 could be inverted, so for example Tree/Cat AND Cat/Tree on sheet 2 would need to return the value for Cat/Tree on sheet 1. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Ok. If it helps, I can help you solve that problem at least. It's a bit much to put into a comment, so I'll just put it in as answer below, understanding it's not a 100% solution but may help you find one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
=ArrayFormula((IFERROR(VLOOKUP(R2:R&S2:S,{O2:O&P2:P,Q2:Q},2,0))&
               IFERROR(IF((R2:R<>"")*(S2:S<>""),VLOOKUP(R2:R&S2:S,{P2:P&O2:O,Q2:Q},2,0),""))))
```

***(Do adjust locale and ranges according to your needs)***

[image]

---

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)

Comment: I put this is in my sheet and it worked, but it also filled the entire column. What would I need to change so it only fills the cell? Also, how do I have it return a blank cell on an error? Right now it is filling in the blanks as another value on the sheet, even if I change the IFERROR [value if false] value to "". Other than that this is wonderful, thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I cannot understand your comment. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Answered my own first question. Answer to my first question was to limit the formula to only the cells I wanted to fill (duh). The second question is still open though. I've shared a sheet here - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gJDQyFf3jed4Vzniz1KWQ0tblCJ8zVxoAfO8bmZEb24/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thanks for sharing this slick technique.

Comment: @Falcon4ch, When I use your test spreadsheet and just delete your "Other Data" label, it reverts to blanks just fine. But I think the way it's actually working when you have that in there is you're effectively telling it that if column 1 and column 2 in your lookup are both blank (the two columns left of your other data label are blank), consider THAT a key-match when your lookup pairs are also blank (i.e. the row isn't filled in), which then returns column 3 for all your empty sheet-2 rows resulting in "Other Data" appearing..

Comment: FYI, if you weren't familiar with arrayFormula (as I wasn't), this page helped me understand how to think about it: https://www.benlcollins.com/spreadsheets/array-formula-intro/ -- Feels very much like a "loop until input range is exhausted" construct.

Comment: @Atmas Please also check the official help pages for the functions used in the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use two keys concated in the lookup table as a virtual key (i.e. make a key like "CAT|DOG"), then you can use that to look in the secondary table.

If you can't guarantee the sort order of the two keys in the secondary table, you can use the following technique to "sort" the two keys so you can make a single lookup key that's always in one stable order.

### Sample Table

| A | B | C | D | E | SortedKey |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Dog | TRUE | Cat | Dog | CatDog |
| Dog | Cat | FALSE | Cat | Dog | CatDog |

### Formulas

Sample formulas for row #1.

- For column C, use formula: `=A1<B1`
- For column D, use formula: `=IF(C1=TRUE, A1, B1)`
- For column E, use formula: `=IF(C1=TRUE, B1, A1)`
- For SortedKey, use formula: `=concat(D1, E1)`